# Crunch generate specific dictionary

Tags: linux, bash

Does anyone knows if it is possible to generate a range of words in crunch that has 10 characters with letters (uppercase) and numbers, but force to have at least three numbers?

For example i can easy generate passwords with both (Extremely huge list),
but i don't need the AAAAAAAAAA OR BBBBBBBBBB. Others like AAA1AAAAAA OR EEEEEE2EEE doesn't apply to my case.

Words like AAA333AAAA or BBBBB245DD is what i need.

I have tried the command crunch:

```
crunch 10 10 "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

But this will give me that huge list.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can.
It's not that difficult to write a program that'll be able to do it.
Question is, will it be worth it to you?

Right now, you're trying to generate
`36^10` numbers.

On my `i5`,  `crunch`, with the above command gives me (`crunch 10 10  "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" | pv >/dev/null`) output at a rate of about `20MBps` ~ `1906501 lines per second (20×2^20/11)`, utilizing 2 out of my 4 virtual cores.
At that current rate, it would calculate all of it in
`36^10÷(20×2^10÷11) seconds ==`62,270 years`

If you were to modify the algorithm so that it would generate a subset that has at least 3 digits, you'd cut the time down
`36^10÷(36^7×10^3) = 46 times` (but the added logic would slow it down a little so the speed up would probably be a little less, although maybe `crunch` isn't as efficient as it could be).

Making it utilize all of my 4 cores could potentially speed it up twice.
To put it shortly you're looking at hundreds of years of computation if you use a common laptop.

There's a reason we use passwords and string tokens to guard access to bank accounts. :)

Comment: I was thinking the same way, but i was thinking to do a little test, because i just used  "https://howsecureismypassword.net/", and they say that takes to 10 days to crack my password, with a desktop computer, maybe using gpu... And i just wanted to verify if it's really like that. Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: I played with it a little, and I can do 280MBps (as opposed to crunch's original 20MBps) or about 140–150MBps with nonconforming results filtered out (which is tantamount to 6440–6900 MBps ~ 185 years on a single laptop; A week for 10,000 CPUs).